# Remove parent node in php

Tags: php, xml

I want to remove all product with category=phones from my xml:

```
<SHOP>
  <ITEM>
    <CATEGORY>Computers</CATEGORY>
    <NAME>DELL</NAME>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <CATEGORY>Computers</CATEGORY>
    <NAME>IBM</NAME>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <CATEGORY>Phones</CATEGORY>
    <NAME>Apple</NAME>
  </ITEM>
</SHOP>
```

I tried this solutions:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->load('product.xml');
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('ITEM/CATEGORY');

for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {     
    $node = $nodes->item($i);       
    if ($node->nodeValue == 'Phones') {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }         
}
```

But it delete only attribute CATEGORY but I need to delete all ITEM node with thit category. How should i change the code?

Comment: Side note: Stack works best when you scratch other people's backs as they did for you in past questions ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I bet this is hard to understand)

Comment: @u_mulder once they start feeling just how good it is, they'll probably want to do it to their own dog.

Comment: As for OP - just get parent of a parent and remove it.

Comment: @user2329752 You should really consider going back through your questions, and accept them if they solved your issue. That way, you both earn reputation, and support people who are willing to help.

Comment: *"I bet this is hard to understand"* - yeah, you're right @u_mulder what on earth was I thinking in trying to make this (world) a better place? I should be sent in exile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were removing category from item. You want to remove item from shop (Both parents). Easiest way to do this:

```
$node->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($node->parentNode);
```

See it in action [at 3v4l here](https://3v4l.org/Ysq3u):

```
<?php

$xml_string = <<<EOT
<SHOP>
  <ITEM>
    <CATEGORY>Computers</CATEGORY>
    <NAME>DELL</NAME>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <CATEGORY>Computers</CATEGORY>
    <NAME>IBM</NAME>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <CATEGORY>Phones</CATEGORY>
    <NAME>Apple</NAME>
  </ITEM>
</SHOP>
EOT;

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml_string);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('ITEM/CATEGORY');

for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {     
    $node = $nodes->item($i);
    if ($node->nodeValue == 'Phones') {
        $node->parentNode->parentNode->removeChild($node->parentNode);
    }         
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I need.

Comment: It really work on my SitemapGenerator, best answer !